# Invariant violation : App(...) Nothing was returned from render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to render component based on the promise from `AsyncStorage` and I am getting this error:

> Exception: Invariant Violation: App(...): Nothing was returned from
>   render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to
>   render nothing, return null.

I know for sure the components are good because I tried to render each of them individually and they're both worked just fine, it's when Im trying to render it through `AsyncStorage.getItem` I cant make it done.

CODE:

```
checkToken = () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('user')
        .then((res) => {
            res = JSON.parse(res)
            console.log('this is checkToken()',res.token)
            // this.renderUserSection(res.token);
            return res.token;   
        })
        .then((token) => {
          return (
             <View style={styles.container}> 
                {!token ? this.renderUser() : this.renderApp()} 
             </View>
          )  
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err)
        })
}



render() {
    return (
        this.checkToken() 
    ) 
}
```

When I did :

```
render() {
    return (
        this.renderUser() 
    ) 
}
```

It worked great!

Also when I did:

```
render() {
    return (
        this.renderApp() 
    ) 
}
```

It worked as well, so the functions are good, is the logic or something at the top one that I can't make work.

Comment: Ara you sure that **this** inside the response from the promise actualy points to the object that has the renderuser renderApp functions?

Comment: when you declare functions with arrow function in ES6 you bind the `this` to it.

Comment: Ok, it was only to discart that the functions were inside another scope or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AsyncStorage` is asynchronous, so it doesn't immediately return the view you have written. You need to display a spinner or a custom view until AsyncStorage has retrieved your data.

Here's a solution:

```
constructor() {
    this.state = {
        token: null
    }
    this.checkToken();
}

checkToken = () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('user')
    .then((res) => {
      res = JSON.parse(res)
      console.log('this is checkToken()',res.token)
      // this.renderUserSection(res.token);
    })
    .then((token) => {
        this.setState({token: token})  
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
}

render() {
    if (this.state.token == null) {
       return (<View> {this.renderUser()} </View>)
    }
    else {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}> 
               {this.renderApp()}
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't storing the `token` in state considered unsafe?

Comment: @FabioLolli I don't think so. it's stored in AsyncStorage anyway, which is unencrypted.

Comment: well, the problem with that method is that the `state` is refreshed each time the user close the app so he would have to log in back each time. This was the first method I tried but it's not fit for storing and checking tokens. I have to find a way to check and render based on the actual `AsyncStorage`

Comment: @obiwankenoobi I don't think user will need to login each time. each time the view is rendered, it fetches token from storage and will have some value, there's no difference with checking the actual `AsyncStorage`.

Comment: what inside the `constructor` will be invoked on each rendering cycle?

Comment: `constructor` is called **once**, when you create an instance from the component class. It is used to create initial state and objects.

Comment: omg man you saved my life and you dont even know that. I tried this method everybody mentioned here LONG time ago but without invoking `checkToken` inside the `constructor` and now I tried it out and it worked like a charm. So... thanks man! you saved my week.

Comment: I'm glad it was useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, checkToken is a function that:

- calls AsyncStorage
- returns undefined

So if the logs tell you that render returned nothing, the logs are right!

You should add a return statement to your checkToken.

Then I suppose we should get to part 2, now check token is a function that:

- calls AsyncStorage
- returns a Promise that the executed function will be returned

It does not really work... React renders components, not promises!

My take is that you need to refactor how this works. My suggestion:

- refactor checkToken into a function that, if getItem succeeds, calls setState({ content: })
- if it fails, setState({ content: null })
- in your render function, do not return the function call. Instead, return state.content
- IF you want to check the token AT EVERY RENDER, call checkToken just before returning state.content from render.
- IF you want to check the token just once, call checkToken in componentDidMount instead - or wherever you need.

This is a sample of what I think the code should look like. You should think about what's the best place to call checkToken.

```
  checkToken = () => {
    let self = this;
    AsyncStorage.getItem('user')
    .then((res) => {
      res = JSON.parse(res)
      console.log('this is checkToken()',res.token)
      // this.renderUserSection(res.token);
      return res.token;   
    })
    .then((token) => {
      self.setState({
        content: (<View style={styles.container}> 
          {!token ? self.renderUser() : self.renderApp()} 
        </View>)
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      self.setState({ content: null })
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
render() {
  //are you sure you need to call checkToken here? Maybe there's a better place? if there is no shouldComponentUpdate this could cause an infinite re-render loop
  //you could maybe call it for componentDidMount, or some other lifecycle method?
  //otherwise I think you'll need that shouldComponentUpdate implementation.
  this.checkToken();
  return this.state.content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use state to store the token first. (The method you have 'checkToken' is a void method)

```
checkToken = () => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('user')
        .then((res) => {
          res = JSON.parse(res)
          console.log('this is checkToken()',res.token)
          // this.renderUserSection(res.token);
          return res.token;
          this.setState(state => ({
            ...state,
            token : res.token
          }))
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err)
        })
      }

      render () {
        const { token } = this.state;
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}> 
              {
                !token 
                  ? this.renderUser() 
                  : this.renderApp()
               } 
          </View>
        )
      }
```

Comment: Isn't storing a variable called `token` in the state supposed to be unsafe?

Comment: @FabioLolli Not sure if its safe or not, but you can simply keep a bool since you only need to know if it exists or not.

Comment: well, the problem with that method is that the `state` is refreshed each time the user close the app so he would have to log in back each time. This was the first method I tried but it's not fit for storing and checking tokens. I have to find a way to check and render based on the actual `AsyncStorage`